# UIActivity view controller in Swift

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to use UIActivity view controller,When i click on sharing button then share sheet open...
I want to make a separate UIActivity controller class using callBack method.and how we use in another view controller class

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I was searching on internet and run the demo project ...But I want to use uiactivityviewcontroller in my project  when I will click on sharing icon ..I am using swift